# Using precompiled header in a project that's already using header-only libraries?

Tags: c++, libraries, precompiled-headers, header-only, stb-image

I'm building a project and I wanted to make a precompiled header to boost performance. The issue is that I'm also using stbi_image headers in my project, which means I would have to include my header on all the stbi files in my project AND make sure there is no duplicate header declarations in any of them.

Is there another way to include stbi or a way to bypass including the precompiled header in those files?

Comment: You might want to specify your compiler and build system.  Setting things up for precompiled headers is quite specific to those.

Comment: *'stbi files in my project"* - aren't those headers from external library? *" I would have to include my header on all the stbi files"* - this does not make any sense. One typically includes library headers into precompiled header, not other way around.